# nginx, django, gunicorn on digital ocean can't reach domain. Bad Request(400)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I can reach my site when going to my IP address but I can not when I go to my domain name.

Here is my **nginx config** file (I have changed the IP and domains for privacy):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.ip.address example.com www.example.com;

    location = /facivon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/tony/vp/vp/config/;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock;
        }
}
```

And this is my productions settings.py file:

```
from .base import *
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', 'my.ip.address', 'example.com', '.example.com']
ROOT_URLCONF = "urls.production_urls"

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_SSL_DIRECT = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'vp',
        'USER': 'vp',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["VP_DB_PASS"],
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL ='media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

And yes my domain is connected to digital ocean.

What could be causing the Bad Request?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

For some reason I have more than one error.log for nginx. It has probably something to do with my many attempts on getting this fixed. Below you can find the relevant error.log:

```
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *7 open socket #12 left in connection 4
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *10 open socket #13 left in connection 6
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *11 open socket #14 left in connection 7
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *13 open socket #16 left in connection 9
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *14 open socket #17 left in connection 10
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: *15 open socket #18 left in connection 11
2017/04/23 17:44:56 [alert] 17723#17723: aborting
2017/04/23 23:26:15 [emerg] 20136#20136: unknown directive "cd" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vp:1
2017/04/23 23:27:12 [emerg] 20147#20147: unknown directive "cd" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vp:1
2017/04/23 23:37:43 [alert] 20399#20399: *12 open socket #14 left in connection 7
2017/04/23 23:37:43 [alert] 20399#20399: *7 open socket #18 left in connection 9
2017/04/23 23:37:43 [alert] 20399#20399: aborting
```

The line: unknown directive "cd" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vp:1 is fixed.

When checking the status of gunicorn I get the following:

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-04-23 14:52:07 UTC; 19h ago
 Main PID: 16044 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4
   Memory: 86.6M
      CPU: 42.667s
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─16044 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/python3 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application
           ├─16049 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/python3 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application
           ├─16050 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/python3 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application
           └─16051 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/python3 /home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application

Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16044] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16044] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock (16044)
Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16044] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16049] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16049
Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16050] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16050
Apr 23 14:52:07 vp-first gunicorn[16044]: [2017-04-23 14:52:07 +0000] [16051] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16051
Apr 23 15:27:51 vp-first systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Apr 23 17:12:36 vp-first systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Apr 23 17:31:37 vp-first systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Apr 23 23:35:18 vp-first systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
```

Comment: Check your nginx error log for a detailed error message, and include it in your question. By default, the nginx error log is located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Also, what WSGI engine are you using with nginx? Gunicorn? uWSGI? Good luck!

Comment: What `url/view` are you trying to reach? How are your `urls` set up?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='landingpage'),
]

Comment: Can you reach the admin or a different url?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Nope. I can not. But when I visit my IP address I can access the main page and admin.

Comment: Do you have the allowed hosts set correctly? I mean is the domain set?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid my ALLOWED_HOSTS can be viewed above in my settings file. And if you mean if I have spelled my domain correct in my actual settings file then yes.

Comment: Sorry! I am an idiot. I even read that before.

Comment: For a quick test, try replacing the allowed hosts with `['*']`

Comment: Done that nothing happened

Comment: I see you got it sorted! Congrats =) You should post your solution below.